# IRB won't read input after pasting over 1565 characters on Windows?

Tags: ruby, powershell, cmd, irb

Though I can paste any size string into Ruby's IRB prompt if it's running in a Unix shell (like Bash on Mac or Linux), when I try to paste my clipboard contents into IRB running on a Windows command/PowerShell prompt, if my clipboard contains larger than 1,565 characters IRB fails to receive the input.  Not only that, after the paste attempt, IRB will not receive any further input from my keyboard (stdin).

Does anyone else have this issue or know a fix to it so I can paste longer strings into IRB?  If you'd like to recreate it, try to paste this integer (1,566 characters long) into the IRB prompt:

```
 012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890012345678901234
```

I have recreated this issue on two Windows 7 machines, one running Ruby 2.1.8p440 and one running Ruby 2.2.0.

**EDIT:**

Sometimes I need to increase the size of the string larger than 1,566-1,700 characters to recreate the bug, but it never seems to handle anything larger than 2000 characters.

Comment: Do you regularly need to paste two-thousand-digit integers into irb? If this is part of your day-to-day work it seems like there must be a better option, like reading it from a file. Failing that, might I suggest the [clipboard](https://github.com/janlelis/clipboard) gem, or switching to Pry and using [pry-clipboard](https://github.com/hotchpotch/pry-clipboard)?

Comment: Not 2,000 digit integers, that was just to illustrate the bug -- it applies to any 2,000 character long code-snippet.  Frequently we paste and hot-swap long segments of Ruby source files/classes in order to debug small parts of our application without having to reload/rerun everything.  Pry helps, but doesn't work as well as IRB for many of our use cases.  The clipboard gem looks like a great way to jerry-rig a work around the issue for now, but I'm curious why the Windows command-line suffers from this bug whereas the Linux and Mac shell interpreters do not.

Comment: This could be a limitation of your terminal because I'm not aware of any such limits in `irb` itself.